# JavaMelody returns Not Found on Tomcat6

Tags: tomcat, java-melody

I'm trying to setup JavaMelody according to their [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#Setup). Everything works on my dev machine, but once deployed to the test environment, I get "404 Not Found. The requested URL /monitoring was not found on this server."

I access JavaMelody on my local machine as `http://localhost:8080/monitoring`, and on the test `http://myapp/monitoring`. myapp is the ROOT application on Tomcat.

Here's the relevant excerpt from the web.xml file

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
    <filter-class>net.bull.javamelody.MonitoringFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>monitoring</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
<listener>
    <listener-class>net.bull.javamelody.SessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Answer (score 0):

Whether is it still a ROOT app on test env? If it is, it should be http:///monitoring